# Error in showing data in custom listview from SQL database

Tags: android, database, android-layout, listview

I want to get data from database and show this data into a custom listview. I have made a custom list view with two textviews and I have an id autoincremented and name and a value in a database.

I want to display that name and the value in the custom listview textview. I am new in Android.

```
public class List_View_Data extends AppCompatActivity {
    database db;
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list__view__data);
        db=new database(this);
        show_data_sql();
    }

    private void show_data_sql(){
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_list__view__data);
        ArrayList<String> thelist=new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data=db.show_data();
        if(data.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else{
                while (data.moveToNext()){
                thelist.add(data.getString(1));
                thelist.add(data.getString(2));
                }
            //BaseAdapter is a very generic adapter that allows you to do pretty much whatever you want.
            //using baseadapter which have listadapter and spinneradapter
            Adapter listAdapter=new Adapter(this,data);
            {
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }
        }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7bDS.png

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sajidamin.digital_tasbeh/com.example.sajidamin.digital_tasbeh.List_View_Data}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: at com.example.sajidamin.digital_tasbeh.Adapter.<init>(Adapter.java:0)
                                                                                        at com.example.sajidamin.digital_tasbeh.List_View_Data.show_data_sql(List_View_Data.java:37)
                                                                                        at com.example.sajidamin.digital_tasbeh.List_View_Data.onCreate(List_View_Data.java:21)

Comment: ^ Please add that extra information by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47095999/edit), thanks.

Comment: the error is shown now

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you link the trace for the error ?

I think you have issue with your index :

```
thelist.add(data.getString(1));
```

The index start at 0

Second, are you sure it's a String you get ?

Comment: yes its a name and its a string. and i try at index 0 still same erroe